# Can I request for Carta D’identità with the receipt of Permesso di Soggiorno?

Tags: italy

I have the receipt of a *permesso di soggiorno* for Italy, having just renewed it a few days ago.

Can I now apply for a *carta d’identità* using that receipt from the post office?

Comment: No need for any of those capital letters! ;)

Comment: @DaG I have restored the original lower case letters.  The capitalization was introduced in an edit by another user.

Answer (score 1):

For a **renewal**, many towns will accept the receipt, yes. Some towns stipulate that the receipt must be dated within 60 days of the expiration of the old *permesso* (i.e., you need to have renewed before the old one expired or no more than 2 months after). You should check with your specific town hall/*comune*, however, as bureaucratic consistency is never guaranteed in Italy.